# Need help creating an array and editing it in another function and send it back to the initial function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, pass-by-reference

I made an array in int main that is passed to GenerateMap, then the GenerateMap function goes through the array and assigns each item. After each item is assigned, I wanted it to go back into int main so I can use it for later but I keep getting errors. After a few attemps, I followed Thenewboston's directions by passing the array by reference. But still I am getting errors in the code. Can someone explain to me what I should do the create the map in the other function?

ERRORS

---

> `prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:22:17: error: cannot convert 'std::string (*)[MapDimension][MapDimension] {aka std::basic_string<char> (*)[MapDimension][MapDimension]}' to 'std::string** {aka std::basic_string<char>**}' for argument '1' to 'void GenerateMap(std::string**)'
>    GenerateMap(&Map);
>                    ^
>   prog.cpp: In function 'void GenerateMap(std::string**)':
>   [NEW ERROR]       prog.cpp:70:31: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
>                   cout <<"[" << *Map[i][j] << "]" << "  ";`

CODE

---

```
int main() {
string Map[MapDimension][MapDimension];
GenerateMap(&Map);

}





void GenerateMap(string *Map[]) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  string x;

for (int i = 0; i <= MapDimension-1; ++i) {

    for (int j = 0; j <= MapDimension-1; ++j) 

            {

            int random = rand() % 6;
                switch  (random) 
                {
                     case 0:
                      x = " D ";
                      break;

                      case 1:
                      x = " F ";
                      break;

                      case 2:
                      x = " P ";
                      break;

                      case 3:
                      x = " M ";
                      break;

                      case 4:
                      x = " L ";
                      break;

                      case 5:
                      x = " S ";
                      break;
                }

            Map[i][j] = x;

            cout <<"[" << *Map[i][j] << "]" << "  ";
            }
    cout << endl;

}




}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon:

```
string Map[MapDimension][MapDimension]
```

should be

```
string Map[MapDimension][MapDimension];
```

Comment: Ooh oops. I fixed that but now theres two different errors

Comment: Ok, now change the declaration of GenerateMap(string *Map[]) to GenerateMap(string *Map[MapDimension][MapDimension]) or to at least GenerateMap(string *Map[MapDimension][])

Comment: The errors say that they can't convert the string to character but i'm not trying to convert it.

Comment: sorry, It should be: GenerateMap(string Map[MapDimension][MapDimention]) and then call it using GenerateMap(map)